# USB/Smartcard rdp Passthrough

Tags: fedora, windows, smartcard, xfreerdp

Im trying to get the USB/Smartcard (Datev Smartcard Reader) redirected to my Windows Server 2019 Remote Desktop Service from my Fedora 31 machine. I tried `rdesktop` and `xfreerdp` but none of them are showing the results im looking for.

What have i tried:

- I installed `opensc ccid pcsc-lite pcsc-tools` and started the pcscd service in order to get it working in fedora. (Even if i think this is not necessary because its a Smartcard Reader not the smartcard)
- I tried to redirect it with `rdesktop` with the following commands: 
  `rdesktop -u $USER -d WINDOWS -r scard rds.my.tld`, here the conecction got stuck in the windows login screen. When i removed the `-r scard` everything worked well so there must be a problem with this switch somehow.
- I tried to redirect it with `xfreerdp` with the following commands:

  `xfreerdp -d WINDOWS -u $USER /usb:dbg,dev:VENDOOR:DEVICE rds.my.tdl`

  `xfreerdp -d WINDOWS -u $USER /usb:rules:allow rds.my.tdl`

  `xfreerdp -d WINDOWS -u $USER /usb:auto rds.my.tdl`

  `xfreerdp -d WINDOWS -u $USER /usb:VENDOOR:DEVICE rds.my.tdl`

  `xfreerdp -d WINDOWS -u $USER /smartcard rds.my.tdl`

With `xfreerdp` every session worked well but no device was visible anywhere. scardsvr on Windows is enabled and started. I installed all datev tools to make sure drivers are correctly installed. And even tried a normal usb data stick. That did not work too. I have no clue anymore. Am i missing something in windows?

```
# xfreerdp --version
This is FreeRDP version 2.0.0-dev5 (n/a)

# rdesktop --version
Version 1.9.0. Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Matthew Chapman et al.
```